# Retrieve SQL Values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table student with columns: `StudID`, `Name`, and `StudNIC`.

I have another table studentBack with columns : `StudBackID`, and `StudMID`

I have another table studentLab with columns : `StudBackID`.

When I perform a `WHERE` condition for a specific student on table `studentLab`, no records is returned.

I want to retrieve the Name of those students having no records in `studentLab`. How can I achieve this in SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEFT JOIN` you get `NULL` values under `studentLAB` table column for records absent in `studentLab` table which you can filter in `WHERE` cluase using `IS NULL` condition

```
SELECT student.Name
FROM student
INNER JOIN studentBack ON student.StudID = studentBack.StudMID 
LEFT JOIN studentLab ON studentLab.StudBackID = studentBack.StudBackID
WHERE studentLab.StudBackID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.Name
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN studentBack sb
    ON s.StudID = sb.StudMID
LEFT JOIN studentLab sl
    ON sb.StudBackID = sl.StudBackID
WHERE sl.StudBackID IS NULL
```

The `IS NULL` condition in the `WHERE` clause will be true for those students who did *not* match any records in the `studentLab` table.

Comment: Your query is checking rows that is not exist in **studentBack** instead of **studentLab**. That is sb.StudBackID should be sl.StudBackID

Comment: @Suraz Sorry for the typo